# How to set "--limit" option in Ansible playbook api

Tags: ansible

I'm writing python script to run ansible playbook, using Ansible 2.4.2.0.
As I know there is an option `--limit`, which can limit the Ansible play on a specific host.

For example:
Here is the /etc/ansible/hosts

```ini
[test]  
192.168.0.1  
192.168.0.2
```

Below command will let Ansible only execute *test.yml* on `192.168.0.1`:

```bash
ansible-playbook test.yml --limit="192.168.0.1"
```

I want to know how to set options in ansible playbook api to do the same thing.
I tried add to `limit='192.168.0.1` in options, but it doesn't work.

Below is the Python script I used.

```py
from collections import namedtuple  
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader  
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager  
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager  
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor  
 
loader = DataLoader()  
inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=['/etc/ansible/hosts'])  
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)  
 
Options = namedtuple('Options', ['listtags', 'listtasks', 'listhosts', 'syntax', 'connection','module_path', 'forks', 'remote_user', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'verbosity', 'check', 'diff', 'ask_sudo_pass', 'limit'])  
 
options = Options(listtags=None, listtasks=None, listhosts=None, syntax=None, connection='smart', module_path=None, forks=100, remote_user=None,  become=None, become_method='sudo', become_user='root', verbosity=None, check=False, diff=False, ask_sudo_pass=None, limit='192.168.0.1')  
 
passwords = {}
 
pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=['/home/test.yml'], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, options=options, passwords=passwords)  

pbex.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible is opensourced, so you can always peek into the existing code.

It's here in `ansible-playbook` CLI code:

```py
inventory.subset(self.options.subset)
if len(inventory.list_hosts()) == 0 and no_hosts is False:
    # Invalid limit
    raise AnsibleError("Specified --limit does not match any hosts")
```

<sup>*Source: [Ansible's code source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.4.2.0-1/lib/ansible/cli/playbook.py#L117)*</sup>

So, your case, after your instantiation of `InventoryManager`, you should add:

```py
inventory.subset('192.168.0.1')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It woks.

Comment: Worked for me as well. @duskcrow: You should mark this as the accepted answer so that it can help others as well.