# "--limit" option when calling playbook in Ansible python api

Tags: python, ansible-2.x, ansible-api

I am trying run playbook from withing python code however I do not know how to pass `--limit` option.
It's similar to following [How to set "--limit" option in Ansible playbook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314363/) ,however I think API has changed a bit. I have following inventory:

```
[rhosts]
host_a
host_b
host_c
```

Inside ping.yaml hosts is set `rhosts` but i need to limit it to only run on `host_a,host_c`

This is my code to run the playbook

```
from ansible import context
from ansible.cli import CLI
from ansible.module_utils.common.collections import ImmutableDict
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from simple_term_menu import TerminalMenu

INVENTORY_FILE = 'hosts'

loader = DataLoader()

context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(tags={}, listtags=False, listtasks=False, 
                    listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection='ssh',
                    module_path=None, forks=100, private_key_file=None,
                    ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, 
                    scp_extra_args=None, become=True, become_method='sudo', become_user='root', 
                    verbosity=True, check=False, start_at_task=None,)

inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=[INVENTORY_FILE])

variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory, version_info=CLI.version_info(gitinfo=False))

pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=['ping.yml'], 
                inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, 
                loader=loader, passwords={})

results = pbex.run()
```

I tried to search in Ansible code and only found

```
def get_host_list(inventory, subset, pattern='all'):

        no_hosts = False
        if len(inventory.list_hosts()) == 0:
            # Empty inventory
            if C.LOCALHOST_WARNING and pattern not in C.LOCALHOST:
                display.warning("provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'")
            no_hosts = True

        inventory.subset(subset)

        hosts = inventory.list_hosts(pattern)
        if not hosts and no_hosts is False:
            raise AnsibleError("Specified hosts and/or --limit does not match any hosts")

        return hosts
```

I am can't work out what and where to pass it, if that's the right bit of code.

Comment: What does `inventory.subset('host_a')` gives you, then?

Comment: Did you try to provide a pattern of `host_[ac]`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but where do I actually need to provide it ? In context, inventory, 
variable_manager, pbex,?

Comment: @MaciejGolkowski you do have a variable inventory, just like what is in the question you linked. So you literally have to use the line, `inventory.subset('host_a')`, which is going to apply on your variable is le of instance `InventoryManager`.

Comment: `inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=[INVENTORY_FILE])
inventory.subset('host_a,host_c')`

Comment: So this **is** a duplicate of [Konstantin Suvorov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49314924/2123530) to the question you linked.

Answer (score 0):

I just gave a try with ansible 2.16.2, and It works on my side with a few tweaks.

This is my code :

```
from ansible import context
from ansible.cli import CLI
from ansible.module_utils.common.collections import ImmutableDict
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.plugins.loader import init_plugin_loader

INVENTORY_FILE = 'hosts'

loader = DataLoader()

context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(tags={}, listtags=False, listtasks=False, 
                    listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection='ssh',
                    module_path=None, forks=100, private_key_file=None,
                    ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, 
                    scp_extra_args=None, become=True, become_method='sudo', become_user='root', 
                    verbosity=True, check=False, start_at_task=None, subset='emptygroup',)

init_plugin_loader([])

inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=[INVENTORY_FILE])

variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory, version_info=CLI.version_info(gitinfo=False))

CLI.get_host_list(inventory, context.CLIARGS['subset'])

pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=['ping.yml'], 
                inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, 
                loader=loader, passwords={})

results = pbex.run()
```

You will notice that :

- **A `subset` keywork is used in `context.CLIARGS` definition.** Its value matches the `--limit` parameter when directly given to ansible-playbook CLI.
- **The `get_host_list` static method of `CLI` class is invoked between inventory definition and playbook executor instanciation.** You can find it in ansible source code here : https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.16.2/lib/ansible/cli/playbook.py#L145. It is a wrapper for calling the `subset` method of `InventoryManager` class. Source code here : https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.16.2/lib/ansible/cli/__init__.py#L582
- I needed to initialize the plugin loader. This is not related to your issue, but apparently it is now needed to allow the collection finder (which is instanciated during your run) to use `context.CLIARGS`.

When I run this python code, the `subset='emptygroup'` does not match any host in my inventory, and ansible only output this :

```
PLAY [A play] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************
```